# Professor expressed interest in collaboration, but remains unresponsive and unreliable. How to proceed?

Tags: postdocs, professorship, correspondence

About 6 months ago, when I was searching for postdoc positions, one of the professors whom I contacted encouraged me to write a joint paper to make a possibility of my invitation to his group. I tried to prepare a manuscript during this time, but as a joint work, he has not contributed yet. For instance, he has told me that he send some useful references or put some materials into the work, but never did that. I think he is no longer interested in that. What Should I do? The last time which I sent an email, he replied that he will write something about that to me "tomorrow". Today is almost 10 days after that "tomorrow".

Comment: Having to write a joint paper to obtain a postdoc position is highly unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So he says he's interested but acts like he's not?  Then you are probably not very high on his priority list.  You could e-mail him again after a week or two, but it probably won't get a different outcome. I'd suggest you move on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I move on, I want to continue this work with one of my  colleagues. In this case, is it necessary to inform professor?